# Atlas Scientific pH project - serialEvent3 problems

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I am trying to get this pH project working and I've noticed that the serialEvent3 never sets the boolean value sensor_string_complete to true.  I am not sure if it is actually capturing the values from the probe.  What I want is for every loop through it should grab a pH value and that is not happening right now.  Most times through the loop the serial3 port is not providing any values.  Here is my code:

```
String sensorstring = "";
boolean sensor_string_complete = false;
float pH;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial3.begin(38400); // pH stamp
}

void serialEvent3() {                                 //if the hardware       serial port_3 receives a char
  sensorstring = Serial3.readStringUntil(13);         //read the string until we see a <CR>
  sensor_string_complete = true;                      //set the flag used to tell if we have received a completed string from the PC
}

void loop() {
  getPh();
  if (sensor_string_complete == true) readph();
}

void getPh() {
  Serial.println("we are here");
  Serial3.print("r");
  Serial3.print(13);
}

void readph(){
  Serial.println("read ph here");
  if (isdigit(sensorstring[0])) {
    pH = sensorstring.toFloat();
    Serial.println(pH);
  }
  else{
    Serial.println(sensorstring);
  }

  sensorstring = ""; 
  sensor_string_complete = false;
}
```

This returns values such as
we are here
we are here
we are here
read ph here
7.0
we are here
read ph here
7.0
we are here
we are here
we are here
read ph here
7.0

I want this to return these values every loop.  I expect to see:
We are here
read ph here
7.0
We are here
read ph here
7.0

Any help on this would be great.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a typical Arduino, the delay between `loop()` ending and `loop()` running again is a few microseconds.  `Serial.println()` in `getPh()` is interrupt-driven so that call too takes only a few microseconds.  Writing two bytes with `Serial3.print()` at 38400 bps will take about half a millisecond.  In short, there is plenty of time for `loop()` to run several times before  `serialEvent3()` sets `sensor_string_complete`.

To call  `getPh()` once and `readph()` once per `loop()`, instead of

```
if (sensor_string_complete == true) readph();
```

say

```
while (!sensor_string_complete) {}
readph();
```

This will stall the loop while the pH sensor takes and reports a reading.

Note, in `getPh()` instead of using two separate `Serial3.print()` statements, you can just say `Serial3.print("r\r")`.